# Definition the norm of a law of a random variable

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, notation, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

[image]

This is a result that appear on *Stochastic Integration And Differential Equation* of Philip Protter. The author define $\Vert \mu \Vert $ where $\mu = \mathcal{L}(X_{0})$ ( The law of $X_{0}$). I have never seen a notation like that before. Could someone help me to know what it means? I have been looking at many books but unfortunately, I have not obtained an answer.

What the author means by usual hypotheses is this:
[image]

Comment: It is hard to believe that $||\mu ||$ can be different from 1 for a probability measure $\mu $. In standard notation $|| \mu ||$ is the total variation norm of a complex measure which is 1 for all probability measures.

Comment: For me this is a kind of terminology to make the notation less tedious. If we let $\mu: (E, \mathcal{E}) \to \mathbb{R}_{+} \cup {0}$ where $\mathcal{E}$ is the sigma algebra of subsets of $E$, and we let $\mu(E) =: \Vert \mu \Vert$,  the notation $\Vert \mu \Vert$  may make sense. However, it is obvious that we are talking about probability measures, especially when we talk about the law of a random variable, and this is the part that makes me doubt.